# How to upload images with cloud kit using swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, icloud, cloudkit

How do I upload and load back images from cloud kit with swift?

What attribute type do I use?

[image]

What code do I use? This is the code I use currently...

```
func SaveImageInCloud(ImageToSave: UIImage) {
        let newRecord:CKRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "ImageRecord")
        newRecord.setValue(ImageToSave, forKey: "Image")

        if let database = self.privateDatabase {


            database.saveRecord(newRecord, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord!, error:NSError! ) in

                if error != nil {

               NSLog(error.localizedDescription)

                }


                else {

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

println("finished")

                    }
                }
        })
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a CKAsset and add that to your record. You can do that with code like this:

```
func SaveImageInCloud(ImageToSave: UIImage) {
    let newRecord:CKRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "ImageRecord")

    let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
    if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true) {
        if paths.count > 0 {
            if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String {
                let writePath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Image2.png")
                UIImagePNGRepresentation(ImageToSave).writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true)

                var File : CKAsset?  = CKAsset(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: writePath))
                newRecord.setValue(File, forKey: "Image")

            }
        }
    }

    if let database = self.privateDatabase {
        database.saveRecord(newRecord, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord!, error:NSError! ) in
            if error != nil {
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    println("finished")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something similar to Edwin's answer but a little more compact. I've tested this and it works well.

This example is saving "myImage" UIImageView into "mySaveRecord" CKRecord, just replace those names with your respective ones.

```
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let imageFilePath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("lastimage")
UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage).writeToFile(imageFilePath, atomically: true)
let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath))
mySaveRecord.setObject(asset, forKey: "ProfilePicture")
CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.saveRecord(mySaveRecord, completionHandler: {
    record, error in
    if error != nil {
        println("\(error)")
    } else {
        //record saved successfully!
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I created this little extension in **Swift 5** to convert from `UIImage` to `CKAsset`:

```
extension UIImage {
    func toCKAsset(name: String? = nil) -> CKAsset? {
        guard let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let imageFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
                .appendingPathComponent(name ?? "asset#\(UUID.init().uuidString)")
        else {
            return nil
        }

        do {
            try self.pngData()?.write(to: imageFilePath)
            return CKAsset(fileURL: imageFilePath)
        } catch {
            print("Error converting UIImage to CKAsset!")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

You can then use it as you have it in your question:

```
if let asset = ImageToSave.toCKAsset() {
    newRecord.setObject(asset, forKey: "Image")

    CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.saveRecord(newRecord, completionHandler: {
      record, error in
      if error != nil {
        println("\(error)")
      } else {
        // saved successfully!
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks KBog!!

Answer (score 0):

This answer works with Swift 2.2 & iOS 9, and separates the file creation from the upload so that you can properly test against both, since they are distinct actions with their own potential issues.

For the uploadPhoto function, the recordType variable is the value you use in your CloudKit dashboard. The "photo" key in the `photo["photo"] = asset` line is the field name for your record type.

```
func uploadPhoto(image: UIImage, recordName: String) {
    let privateDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase
    let photoID = CKRecordID(recordName: recordName)
    let photo = CKRecord(recordType: recordType, recordID: photoID)
    let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: writeImage(image))
    photo["photo"] = asset

    privateDB.saveRecord(photo) { (record, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)

            return
        }
        print("Successful")
    }
}

func writeImage(image: UIImage) -> NSURL {
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(NSUUID().UUIDString + ".png")
    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        imageData.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: false)
    }

    return fileURL
}
```

You can call this with the following:

```
uploadPhoto(UIImage(named: "foo.png")!, recordName: "bar")
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to pick the Asset value type in the dashboard for this value.

`newRecord.setValue(ImageToSave, forKey: "Image")`

UIImage is not an allowed type on `CKRecord`. Your best option is to write this image out to a file, then create a `CKAsset` and set that on the record.